mdadm force all drives to be used in a [re-]sync
I have a 2 disk MD raid1 array.  One of the drives is slow so I want to replace it.  But for paranoia[1] and safety's sake, I want to add the new (3rd) drive and sync it before removing the slow drive, since, well, it's just slow, but otherwise is working and has valid data on it and I want to avoid degrading the array before I have to.
So I've added the third disk and it's started syncing, so all is good so far.  But it's only using 1 of the existing 2 drives as the source of the sync, and wouldn't you know it according to what I call the 50/50/90 rule[2], it's using the slow disk as the (only) source of the sync.  I can see that it's (only) using the slow disk using sar:
01:21:55 PM       tps     rkB/s     wkB/s     dkB/s   areq-sz    aqu-sz     await     %util DEV
01:22:00 PM     91.60      0.00  45147.30      0.00    492.87      0.14      1.48     11.26 sdb
01:22:00 PM      0.40      0.00      1.70      0.00      4.25      0.13    314.00     48.08 sde
01:22:00 PM     91.60  45145.60      1.70      0.00    492.87      3.41     37.26     88.30 sdd
01:22:00 PM      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00 md0

sdd is the slow disk.  If MD were reading from sde instead, the speed would be about 4x that:
# dd if=/dev/sde of=/dev/null bs=1M count=5000
5000+0 records in
5000+0 records out
5242880000 bytes (5.2 GB, 4.9 GiB) copied, 23.1946 s, 226 MB/s

Frankly I am surprised that MD is being that simplistic and that it doesn't read from all of the disks when rebuilding, for exactly this kind of reason/case.
So, is there any way I can force the use of sde in this sync, either in addition to sdd or instead of it?
P.S. The sync speed is not being limited by dev.raid.speed_limit_max:
# sysctl -n dev.raid.speed_limit_max
20000000

[1] Call me paranoid, but you know the moment that your array is down to a single disk is when that single disk is going fail.
[2] If you have a 50/50 chance of something happening one way or the other, 90% of the time it will be the way you didn't want.

Regarding footnote 1 – RAID1 systems often have the function to "split" the array, so that you end up with two single-disk arrays, the removed disk effectively acting as a backup copy. (Though even without that, I believe mdraid disks still retain their data after being removed in the normal way?)

Yeah.  I had considered that, after-the-fact (there was no reason to consider it until my surprise).  But once the sync started, and I was surprised by the fact that both existing disks were not being used as the sync source, I didn't really want to interrupt what was successfully under way to go back and split the array.  Rather I was hoping I could somehow influence the existing sync to use either both or at least the faster of the two existing disks.

Use the counter-intuitively named "Write Mostly" option.  This tells MD that it should avoid using the device for reads.  Replace md123 below with the device for your MD array:
echo writemostly > /sys/block/md123/md/dev-sdd/state

Double-check that the state applied:
cat /sys/block/md123/md/dev-sdd/state
in_sync,write_mostly


Thank-you!  This is exactly the sort of solution I was looking for.  Sync speed more than doubled now that the fast drive is being used as the source of the sync.
